# Vimeo video streaming in android,ios and web Vs Youtube

Tags: youtube-api, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

We are developing app which contain video uploading and streaming .We plan to store videos on Vimeo. We refered simple and advance api's. Whether we can play video in android and ios player or do we required to show in web view.Is there any ios and android lib availbale to stream videos. We want to show ONLY VIDEOS. Which URL should be used in this? vimeo.com/videoId OR vimeo.com/m/#/videoId or player.vimeo.com/video/videoId)

If we compare this with Youtube api is there any advantages or disadvantages?

Answer (score 1):

Vimeo provides PRO members direct access to their own video files using their new API 3. At the moment you must request access directly (it's in Closed Beta).

If you use the Advanced API, or do not have a pro account you will need to embed videos using a web view.